# Parsing GET request data with from SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

So I created a simple server on an Ubuntu box on port 8000 by doing this:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

```
10.127.11.18 - - [14/Aug/2014 15:11:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.127.11.18 - - [14/Aug/2014 15:11:55] code 404, message File not found
10.127.11.18 - - [14/Aug/2014 15:11:55] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
10.127.11.18 - - [14/Aug/2014 15:12:02] "GET /crazysean/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.127.11.18 - - [14/Aug/2014 15:12:37] "GET /crazysean/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.127.11.18 - - [14/Aug/2014 15:12:52] "GET /crazysean/?url=www.google.com&x=200&y=400 HTTP/1.1" 301 -
10.127.11.18 - - [14/Aug/2014 15:12:52] "GET /crazysean/?url=www.google.com&x=200&y=400/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.127.11.18 - - [14/Aug/2014 15:13:10] "GET /crazysean/?url=www.google.com&x=200&y=400/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I am trying to parse out the `GET` data that is sent, such as URL, x position and y position.

I assume my first step should be creating a new script like so:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

But I am unsure of how to make amendments to this script to capture the `GET` data, because eventually I want to dump the data into a sqlite3 db.

Comment: Are you trying to save the parsed logs or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: @slipjack Saving the logs would be a good start I suppose.

Comment: @slipjack I guess a better way to put what I am looking for is I want to parse the `GET` requests as they come in.

Comment: You would greatly benefit from using a higher level library like flask.

Comment: @PauloScardine I understand that and I know how to use flask relatively well, but I'm trying to do this as a learning experience.

Comment: What do you mean by "parse the `GET` requests as they come in". `SimpleHTTPServer` already parses the requests; that's how it serves them, and writes the log messages. Are you looking to intercept its parsing and replace it with your own? Or to access the fields it parses out? Or are you looking for a separate program that will parse the logs it generates? Or…?

Comment: @abarnert For example, where is this stored `"GET /crazysean/?url=www.google.com&x=200&y=400 HTTP/1.1" 301 -`?  I want to parse out the URL, the x value and the y value and store them in a sqlite db.  So I guess from your options is this access the fields it parses out, right?

Comment: @Meepl: It's not stored. It's parsed, logged, serviced, and forgotten.

Comment: @abarnert how can I store it?

Comment: The actual command like is `GET HTTP/1.1 /crazysean/?url=www.google.com&x=200&y=400`. You can get the pieces of that by subclassing the handler. If you want the rest of the log information, like the 301, that's not part of the request; that's the handler explaining what it did about the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* this is an XY problem. You have no interest in parsing GET requests, or doing anything with the logs; what you want is to "capture the GET data", in exactly the same way that `SimpleHTTPServer` is using that data to serve the requests, so you can store it in a database. And you just thought the only way to do that was to parse *something*, *somewhere*, but you weren't sure what.

Clearly, `SimpleHTTPServer` must already be parsing the `GET` data, and must have exactly what you want available. So, where is it?

As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) say right at the top:

> A lot of the work, such as parsing the request, is done by the base class [`BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler). This class implements the `do_GET()` and `do_HEAD()` functions.

Follow that link, and you'll see:

> The handler will parse the request and the headers, then call a method specific to the request type. The method name is constructed from the request. For example, for the request method `SPAM`, the `do_SPAM()` method will be called with no arguments. All of the relevant information is stored in instance variables of the handler…

So, everything has been parsed into instance variables; there's a nice list of them below that paragraph below.

So:

```
class DBLoggingHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DBLoggingHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.db = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
    def do_GET(self):
        self.db.execute("INSERT INTO GetLog (command, vers, path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                        (self.command, self.request_version, self.path))
        return super(DBLoggingHandler, self).do_GET()
```

If you want to parse the `path` into separate components, you can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) for that:

```
    def do_GET(self):
        bits = urlparse.urlpase(self.path)
        self.db.execute("""INSERT INTO GetLog (command, vers, scheme, netloc, 
                                               path, params, query, fragment,
                                               username, password, hostname, port)
                           VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""",
                        (self.command, self.request_version, bits.scheme, bits.netloc,
                         bits.path, bits.params, bits.query, bits.fragment,
                         bits.username, bits.password, bits.hostname, bits.port))
        return super(DBLoggingHandler, self).do_GET()
```

Also, remember that requests can have more than just a command line; they usually have headers, and they may have a body (although usually not for `GET`). See `headers` and `rfile` for that. And for information that isn't part of the HTTP request, but part of the socket connection, or information about the server, etc., there are attributes for that too.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you very much.  I've never used a class before, so I have some researching to do.